# How can I set it so item 1 changes when I hover on item 2?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make the function when I hover on item 2 to become bigger and item 1 to shrink and the text inside it to rotate.

Is there a way to do it with CSS or with JavaScript?

So far I managed to make it work when I hover on item 1 and item 2 shrinks.

This is what I have so far:

```css
container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#box1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #154c79;
  height: 600px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  flex: 1;
}

#box1:hover {
  transition: width 2s;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 10;
}

#box1:hover~#box2 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  flex: 1;
}

#box2 {
  position: relative;
  background: #FBCEB1;
  height: 600px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  flex: 1;
}

#box2:hover {
  transition: width 2s;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 10
}

#box2:hover~#box1 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="box1">
    <h2>Box 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <h2>Box 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.item-1:hover {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.item-2:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

**Try this one if it's helpfull**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I want when I hover on item 2, the text in item 1 to rotate as it does when I hover over item 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```css
container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

#box1 {
    position: relative;
    background: #154c79;
    height: 600px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    flex: 1;
}

#box1:hover {
    transition: width 2s;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 10;
}

#box1:hover ~ #box2 {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    text-orientation: upright;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#box2 {
    position:relative;
    background: #FBCEB1;
    height: 600px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    flex: 1;   
}

#box2:hover {
    transition: width 2s;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 10
}

#box1:has(+#box2:hover) {   
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    text-orientation: upright;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
            <div id="box1"> <h2>Box 1</h2>
            <div id="box2"> <h2>Box 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).